# How to save the parse json array values to the database in django python rest api,by using models.py , serializers.py and views.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want save the category and their subcategories to the database and here each category have a multiple subcategories.Could you please help me to save the user,category and multiple subcategories corresponding to category.Models.py , Serializers.py, Views.py and incomming request is attached.

**Models.py**

```
class SavingCategoryandPreferences(models.Model):

   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
   news_category = models.ForeignKey(NewsCategory)
   subcategories= models.ManyToManyField(NewsSubCategory, related_name='sub')
   sort_order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='subcategories_id', separator='', editable=True)
   created_time = models.DateTimeField("Created Date", auto_now_add=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class MobilecatsubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = SavingCategoryandPreferences
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'subcategories', 'news_category',)
```

**Views.py**

```
class MobileCatsubViewswt(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = serializers.MobilecatsubSerializer
  queryset = SavingCategoryandPreferences.objects.all()
```

**Incomming Request**

```
{
 "user":"39",
 "news_category":"22",
 "subcategories": [
    {"sub_id":"1"},
    {"sub_id":"2"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: You've got your model definition reversed. `ForeignKey` is many-to-one, so multiple instances of `SavingCategoryandPreferences` can be related to only one `NewsSubCategory` instance. You should fix your model schema first before moving forward.

Comment: I have changed ForeignKey to   ManyToManyField                                                                                        subcategories= models.ManyToManyField(NewsSubCategory, related_name='sub')

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the updates.

Comment: Thank you for the response question is updated

Comment: If your incoming request has `"subcategories": [1, 2]` instead, you could just use a [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) in your serializer.

Comment: If  incoming request was "subcategories": [1, 2],then how can parse the value.

Comment: Here incoming request is like"subcategories": [
    {"sub_id":"1"},
    {"sub_id":"2"}
  ].can you please help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

By default DRF `serializers.ModelSerializer` defines all related fields as `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`. For to-many relationships (`many=True`) i.e. reverse FK or many-to-many, it *implicitly* creates an instance of `ManyRelatedField` with the original field (`PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in this case) kept as the `child_relation` instance attribute, which in turn is used in the `to_internal_value` method of `ManyRelatedField` to actually do validation for each incoming item (primary keys in this case) passed in as list elements for the field.

The above is a long way of saying that you can only pass the primary keys of the related `NewsSubCategory` instances in a list e.g.:

```
{
 "user":"39",
 "news_category":"22",
 "subcategories": [1, 2]
}
```

You can even pass the primary keys as strings.

---

Now, if you don't have any control over how and in what format the data is passed, you can override `to_internal_value` method of `MobilecatsubSerializer` to extract the primary keys from the input data and update the input data `dict` with them e.g.:

```
class MobilecatsubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SavingCategoryandPreferences
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'subcategories', 'news_category',)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if 'subcategories' in data:
            # Change this if needed
            spams = [dct['sub_id'] for dct in data['subcategories']]
            data.update(subcategories=subcategories)
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

---

If you feel overly ambitious you can go ahead and instead override the `to_internal_value` method of the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` (or anything you use for the field) to do the serialization of the values there, but it would be a bad idea as all other serializers that have `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` also needs to go through this needlessly. But if for some reason, you want to follow this path, it would better to subclass `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, do serialization overriding `to_internal_value` like the way I did above, and set this one explicitly as the serializer for the `subcategories` field.